# awk extract lines with keywords

Tags: awk

A rather simple question. I have two tab delimitated files. The first one is comprised my many columns and the first and second columns are in format like below:

```
RT034_00001 xxxx
RT034_00002 sss
RT034_00003 rrrr
RT034_00004 yrurf
```

I would like to retrieve the lines where first column values are match the following keywords of the second one-column file, for example:

```
RT034_00002
RT034_00004
```

So in the end I would like to come with

```
RT034_00002 sss
RT034_00004 yrurf
```

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by building an array whose keys are the contents of the second file, then printing matching lines in the first:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' second_file first_file
```

Comment: `++` is not really needed here since we never really look at the count. Though I admit, I would have probably done that as well. `;)`

Comment: I forgot that it was sufficient to simply refer to the key. I've edited it out.

Comment: I run      awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1; next}$1 in a' 2.txt 1.txt > 3.txt. Gives an empty file. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @user61677 the first version of my code was incorrect, I have edited it. The current version should work.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -f 2ndfile.txt 1stfile.txt`

will work if

1stfile.txt is

```
RT034_00001 xxxx
RT034_00002 sss
RT034_00003 rrrr
RT034_00004 yrurf
```

and 2ndfile.txt is

```
RT034_00002
RT034_00004
```

[image]

Comment: i have checked that. However it gives again the content of the first file

Comment: Are you sure, because it works in my shell

Comment: Yes it gives the contents of teh fisrt delimitated file

Comment: Sorry, now it works, I have forget a line in the 2nd file.Thanks!!